# how to remove a file named "-f" from the command-line?

Tags: command-line

Here are some options

a) rm -f

b) rm "-f" (double quotes)

c) rm '-f' (single quotes)

d) all of the above

e) none of the above

Comment: This is the least effort somebody has put into disguising their homework questions in a long time

Answer (score 12):

There are two options. You can use `--` to tell `rm` that there are no more options. The second way is to specify the relative or absolute path to the file.

Here are some examples:

```
rm -- -f
rm ./-f
rm /path/to/-f
```

Comment: thanks, so that's e) none of the above, right?

Comment: @siamii, yes, none of the above